# Jquery - Select and Input Box Combo

Tags: jquery

I am trying to do a combo select box and text input. Here is how I would like for it to work.

1. The user sees the old value
2. Clicking on the old value offers a combo text box and select drop box
3. The user can enter text or select an option
4. Whichever is chosen becomes the new value

I have been able to do most of this and you can see it here.

http://jsfiddle.net/jfoxworth/X5BTD/

However, when someone focuses on the input they cannot then go to the drop box without losing focus on the whole thing and "starting over." The reverse is also true. I want the user to be able to go back and forth between the two without losing focus. Is this possible?

I think that the problem I am having lies somewhere in this section:

```
$(".whileloopflagvalue").live("click", function(event) {
    $(this).hide();             
    $(this).parent().find('.whileloopflagselect').show();               
    $(this).parent().find('.whileloopflaginput').show();        
});


$(".whileloopflagselect, .whileloopflaginput").live("focusout", function(event) 
{   
    $(this).parent().find('.whileloopflagselect').hide();               
    $(this).parent().find('.whileloopflaginput').hide();
    var temp=$(this).parent().find('.whileloopflaginput').attr("value");
    if (temp.length==0) { temp=1; }
    $(this).parent().find('.whileloopflagvalue').html(temp);
    $(this).parent().find('.whileloopflagvalue').show();    
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was one of the coolest things I have tried to figure out in a while.

I changed your code first to no longer use `live` since it has been depreciated.

I added all the event handlers to the `document` in the document ready function; delegated where necessary.

I then had to create a flag to tell if the input was dirty. If it was and the newly focused element was not the select or vice versa, then I allowed it to set the value and hide the fields.

[here is what I came up with](http://jsfiddle.net/DpteE/3/):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var oldValue = $('whileloopflagvalue');
    
    $(document).find('.whileloopflagselect').hide();
    $(document).find('.whileloopflaginput').hide();    

    $(document).on('focusin',function(event){
        var theTarget = $(event.target);
        var theInput = theTarget.parent().find('.whileloopflaginput');
        var theSelect = theTarget.parent().find('.whileloopflagselect');
        
        if(theInput.length > 0){
            if(theTarget[0] == theInput[0] || theTarget[0] == theSelect[0]){
                theInput.removeAttr('data-dirty');
            }
        }
        
    });
    
    $(document).on("focusout", function (event) {   
        var theTarget = $(event.target);
        var theInput = theTarget.parent().find('.whileloopflaginput');
        var theSelect = theTarget.parent().find('.whileloopflagselect');
        setTimeout(function(){
            if (theTarget[0] == theInput[0] || theTarget[0] == theSelect[0] ) {
                if(theInput.attr('data-dirty') == 'dirty'){
                    theTarget.parent().find('.whileloopflagvalue').text(theInput.val());
                    theInput.hide();
                    theSelect.hide();
                    theTarget.parent().find('.whileloopflagvalue').show();
                    theInput.removeAttr('dirty');
                }  
            }
        }, 50);
    });

    $(document).on("click",".whileloopflagvalue", function (event) {
        oldValue = $(this).text();
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).parent().find('.whileloopflagselect').show();
        $(this).parent().find('.whileloopflaginput').show().focus();
    });
    
    $(document).on('change','.whileloopflagselect', function () {
        var temp = $(this).attr("id");
        $(this).parent().find(".whileloopflaginput").val($('#' + temp).find(":selected").text());
        $(this).parent().find(".whileloopflaginput").attr('data-dirty','dirty');
        $("#" + temp).val("").attr('selected', true);
    });
    
    $(document).on('input propertychange','.whileloopflaginput',function(){
        $(this).attr('data-dirty','dirty');
    });

});
```

So now if you enter a value in the text box or select a value in the drop down, as long as the next element you select is one of the two, then you can move between them as much as you want.

The reason for the `setTimeout` in the lost focus handler is to allow the browser time to fire the `focusin` event. If you did not do this there would be no way of knowing what element got focus after one of the two controls lost it.

The only quirky thing is that if you do not make any changes, then it will not hide. You must change something if you click the div.